# How to add to querystring on event trigger using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input slider. When i slide the bar, i would like to add the parameters to my url query string.

```
$("#inputslider").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 300,
    max: 4000,
    type: 'double',
    prefix: "$",
    maxPostfix: "+",
    prettify: false,
    hasGrid: true,
    gridMargin: 10,
    onFinish: function(obj) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"/search",
            data: { priceFrom: obj.fromNumber, priceTo: obj.toNumber },
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data) {
               //alert(data.Condition);
            },
            error:function(data){
            }
        });

    }
});
```

This is what i have now. The code will goes under the onFinish trigger.

Something like that:

http://www.flocations.com.sg/tour-packages/from-singapore/to-bali/1?package_types=Free%20and%20Easy,Land%20Tour

Slide the input slider on the left, we can see it changed instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using javascript pushState. Read more info at http://html5doctor.com/history-api/